# Function that return a structure that contains a pointer to array in C

Tags: c, arrays, structure

First few parts of code:

```
    typedef struct
    {
        double sr, med;
        int **t;
    }wynik;

    wynik calc(int *t[], int size)
    {
        int i, *niep = NULL, j = 0, k = 1, sum = 0;
        int *sorted = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
        wynik out;
        //coping, sorting
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            sorted[i] = (*t)[i];
        qsort(sorted, size, sizeof (**t), cmp);
        out.t = &sorted;
...
    return out;
    }
```

then in main():

```
wynik get = calc(&tab, tab_size);
```

Using debugger I discovered that in calc() out.t points to an array, but in main() get.t points to some weird things.
How to fix it?

Comment: Your sturcture doesn't contain an array. It contains a pointer.

Comment: I'm sorry but nothing in this code makes any sense. It would seem you are uncertain about how pointers and arrays work and have therefore obfuscated your program to the point where you no longer know what it does. On top of that you have memory leaks. This code is unsalvageable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`out.t` contains the address of the local variable `sorted`. When the function returns, this address is no longer valid because the local variable went out of scope.

I see no reason here that `out.t` should be `int**` instead of `int*`. If you change it to be `int*` and just set its value with `out.t = sorted`, it should work correctly.

Comment: because he allocated the memory on the heap inside the function, that address should stay valid until it is freed, shouldn't it ?

Comment: @MattKo The address stored inside `sorted` (which was allocated by `malloc`) remains valid until freed. But the address of `sorted` itself (`&sorted`) becomes invalid when returning.

Comment: You're right, I got a bit distracted, this code is not so easy to analyze. Of course, the address of `sorted` is on the stack, but its content on the heap.